# find groups with duplicate versions

Tags: mysql, select, mysql-5.7, group-by, aggregate

I want to find all the groups in a table that have duplicate group version.
A group can have multiple group versions.
Each group version can have multiple members.
A group 'version' is defined by `grpid` and `changeDate`.
A group consider a duplicate if **ALL** the members (`userid`, `pct` and `hobby` ) in one group version matches another group version within the same group.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=84eb81a1a71dcee9ad3d0bd91f56120a

The `groups` table:

| id | grpid | changeDate | userid | pct | hobby | group version<sup>*</sup> |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-01-02 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2020-01-03 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0.5 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2 | 0.5 | 2 | 4 |
| 6 | 2 | 2020-01-02 | 1 | 0.5 | 1 | 5 |
| 7 | 2 | 2020-01-02 | 2 | 0.5 | 3 | 5 |
| 8 | 3 | 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0.5 | 1 | 6 |
| 9 | 3 | 2020-01-01 | 2 | 0.5 | 2 | 6 |
| 10 | 3 | 2020-01-02 | 1 | 0.4 | 1 | 7 |
| 11 | 3 | 2020-01-02 | 2 | 0.6 | 2 | 7 |
| 12 | 4 | 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0.6 | 1 | 8 |
| 13 | 4 | 2020-01-01 | 2 | 0.4 | 2 | 8 |
| 14 | 4 | 2020-01-02 | 1 | 0.6 | 1 | 9 |
| 15 | 4 | 2020-01-02 | 2 | 0.4 | 2 | 9 |
| 16 | 5 | 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0.2 | 2 | 10 |
| 17 | 5 | 2020-01-01 | 2 | 0.5 | 1 | 10 |
| 18 | 5 | 2020-01-01 | 3 | 0.3 | 2 | 10 |
| 19 | 6 | 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0.3 | 2 | 11 |
| 20 | 6 | 2020-01-01 | 2 | 0.5 | 1 | 11 |
| 21 | 6 | 2020-01-01 | 3 | 0.2 | 2 | 11 |
| 22 | 6 | 2020-02-01 | 1 | 0.2 | 2 | 12 |
| 23 | 6 | 2020-02-01 | 2 | 0.5 | 1 | 12 |
| 24 | 6 | 2020-02-01 | 3 | 0.3 | 2 | 12 |
| 25 | 6 | 2020-03-01 | 1 | 0.3 | 2 | 13 |
| 26 | 6 | 2020-03-01 | 2 | 0.3 | 1 | 13 |
| 27 | 6 | 2020-03-01 | 3 | 0.4 | 2 | 13 |
| 28 | 7 | 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0.3 | 2 | 14 |
| 29 | 7 | 2020-01-01 | 2 | 0.5 | 1 | 14 |
| 30 | 7 | 2020-01-01 | 3 | 0.2 | 2 | 14 |
| 31 | 7 | 2020-02-01 | 1 | 0.3 | 2 | 15 |
| 32 | 7 | 2020-02-01 | 2 | 0.5 | 1 | 15 |
| 33 | 7 | 2020-02-01 | 3 | 0.2 | 2 | 15 |
| 34 | 7 | 2020-03-01 | 1 | 0.3 | 2 | 16 |
| 35 | 7 | 2020-03-01 | 2 | 0.3 | 1 | 16 |
| 36 | 7 | 2020-03-01 | 3 | 0.4 | 2 | 16 |
| 37 | 8 | 2020-02-01 | 1 | 0.3 | 1 | 17 |
| 38 | 8 | 2020-03-01 | 1 | 0.3 | 1 | 18 |
| 39 | 8 | 2020-03-01 | 3 | 0.4 | 2 | 18 |

<sup><sup>*</sup>Unique group version number just for visualization.</sup>

Result should be:

```
grpid
1
4
7
```

Explanation:

- grpid 1 - there are 3 group versions (of 1 member) - 1 and 3 duplicate because userid, pct and hobby equal
- grpid 2 - there are 2 group versions (of 2 members) - not duplicate because hobby not equal between 5 and 7
- grpid 3 - there are 2 group versions (of 2 members) - not duplicate because pct is different among all members
- grpid 4 - there are 2 group versions (of 2 members) - all members are duplicate because userid, pct and userid equal
- grpid 5 - there is only one group of 3 members - not duplicate
- grpid 6 - there are 3 group versions (of 3 members) - not duplicate - the pct changed for each member in the group between versions
- grpid 7 - there are 3 group versions (of 3 members) - duplicate because userid, pct and userid equal between 28-30 and 31-33
- grpid 8 - there are 2 group versions one w/ one member and one with 2 members - not duplicate because there is another member in that group

I am using MySQL 5.7.

Comment: **CRITICAL** - what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: And what is a "member"? No such column in the data.

Comment: I have closed the question, until the OP clarifies the question, providing answers to the questions asked.

Comment: I haven't explain the purpose of the `changeDate` hope now it makes sense.

Comment: This is bit better. New data have different userids, so it explains what "member" means. But the result should still not include 1 as the single user there has 2 hobbies: 1,2,1.

Comment: It is also not at all clear why 7 should be included. I see 3 "versions" or grpid 7 (14, 15, 16) and they don't have the same data (userid/pct/hobby). Versions 14 and 15 have the same but version 16 differs.

Comment: If there are two versions that match - this group is duplicate

Comment: ok, sounds good. Looks like a variation on relational division.

Comment: Any idea how to make it into a query?

Comment: @Nir - please see "my" answer! It isn't my work and therefore I don't want any upvotes or it to be marked as correct. You can copy it out, write an answer of your own using this code and then I'll delete my answer! You can let me know by leaving a comment under my answer!

Comment: Under explanation for grpid 1, do you mean: `...because userid, pct and *hobby* equal` ?

Comment: Yes, ty. I've edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this should provide an answser:

This implements "common" relational division:

```
SELECT DISTINCT grpid
FROM groups AS g
GROUP BY grpid, changeDate
HAVING NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT 1
      FROM groups AS gi
      WHERE gi.grpid = g.grpid
        AND gi.changeDate = g.changeDate
        AND NOT EXISTS
            ( SELECT 1 
               FROM groups AS gk
               WHERE gk.grpid = gi.grpid
                 AND gk.changeDate <> gi.changeDate
                 AND gk.userid = gi.userid
                 AND gk.pct = gi.pct
                 AND gk.hobby = gi.hobby
            )
    ) ;
```

Result:

```
grid
   1
   4
   7
```

This implements **exact relational division**, which results in even more complicated code. Your case, where the groupings/versions are determined by two columns `(grpid, changeDate)` makes it look like even more complicated.

Tested in **[dbffdle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ae5e062292fdf2e4b5376449913c4813)**

Query 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT g1.grpid
FROM 
  ( SELECT grpid, changeDate
    FROM groups AS g
    GROUP BY grpid, changeDate
  ) AS g1
  JOIN
  ( SELECT grpid, changeDate
    FROM groups AS g
    GROUP BY grpid, changeDate
  ) AS g2
  ON  g1.grpid = g2.grpid
  AND g1.changeDate < g2.changeDate
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT 1
      FROM groups AS gi
      WHERE gi.grpid = g1.grpid
        AND gi.changeDate = g1.changeDate
        AND NOT EXISTS
            ( SELECT 1 
               FROM groups AS gk
               WHERE gk.grpid = g2.grpid
                 AND gk.changeDate = g2.changeDate
                 AND gk.userid = gi.userid
                 AND gk.pct = gi.pct
                 AND gk.hobby = gi.hobby
            )
    )
   AND NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT 1
      FROM groups AS gi
      WHERE gi.grpid = g2.grpid
        AND gi.changeDate = g2.changeDate
        AND NOT EXISTS
            ( SELECT 1 
               FROM groups AS gk
               WHERE gk.grpid = g1.grpid
                 AND gk.changeDate = g1.changeDate
                 AND gk.userid = gi.userid
                 AND gk.pct = gi.pct
                 AND gk.hobby = gi.hobby
            )
    )
 ;
```

Query 2 that uses MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT` function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT grpid
FROM
  ( SELECT grpid, changeDate, 
           GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT_WS('-', userid, hobby, pct)
                         ORDER BY userid, hobby, pct
                         SEPARATOR '  '
                       ) AS groupdata 
    FROM groups AS gr
    GROUP BY grpid, changeDate
  ) AS g
GROUP BY grpid, groupdata
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ;
```

Comment: for this is needed a recursive cte, as the number can grow as 15 and then 1 10 and so on. in mysql 5.7 this will need a stiored proceedure to handle that in  a loop and more

Comment: @nbk no, you don't  need a CTE! See above!

Comment: hate to keep changing the question but you query while is the closest answer, is missing when there is same rows but member count is different (see group 8)

Comment: Query 2 is the simplest one and it was what I was looking for. Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a inner join for that

Fyi mysql 8 duesn't like groups as table name, and must be put in backticks

And lines id = 2 and and id = 4, are also "identical, and fall under your rule

> ```
> create table groups ( id int,  grpid int , changeDate date,  userid int,  pct double ,  hobby int );
> ```

> ```
> insert into groups(id , grpid , changeDate  ,userid  ,pct  ,hobby ) values
> (1  , 1      ,'2020-01-01', 1   ,    1   , 1  ),
> (2  , 1      ,'2020-01-02', 1   ,    1   , 2  ),
> (3  , 1      ,'2020-01-03', 1   ,    1   , 1  ),
> (4  , 2      ,'2020-01-01', 1   ,    0.5 , 1  ),
> (5  , 2      ,'2020-01-01', 1   ,    0.5 , 2  ),
> (6  , 2      ,'2020-01-02', 1   ,    0.5 , 1  ),
> (7  , 2      ,'2020-01-02', 1   ,    0.5 , 3  ),
> (8  , 3      ,'2020-01-01', 1   ,    0.5 , 1  ),
> (9  , 3      ,'2020-01-01', 1   ,    0.5 , 2  ),
> (10 , 3      ,'2020-01-02', 1   ,    0.4 , 1  ),
> (11 , 3      ,'2020-01-02', 1   ,    0.6 , 2  ),
> (12 , 4      ,'2020-01-01', 1   ,    0.6 , 1  ),
> (13 , 4      ,'2020-01-01', 1   ,    0.4 , 2  ),
> (14 , 4      ,'2020-01-02', 1   ,    0.6 , 1  ),
> (15 , 4      ,'2020-01-02', 1   ,    0.4 , 2  );
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT g1.grpid 
> FROM `groups` g1 INNER JOIN  `groups` g2
> ON g1.grpid = g2.grpid 
> AND g1.hobby = g2.hobby 
> AND g1.pct = g2.pct 
> AND g1.userid = g2.userid
> WHERE g1.id <> g2.id
> ```
>
> ```
> | grpid |
> | ----: |
> |     1 |
> |     2 |
> |     4 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=82e8acb87a1fae49204bed2c197d1a2c)*

Comment: your SQL return `2` as well, which shouldn't. the hobby is different in one of the members which makes it a different group

Comment: check line 4 and 6 as i wrote  in my answer, the are they same except the date, that is the same as for the the group id 4 or 2 for that matter

Comment: yes, but as a group - they are different because 5 and 7 are different. As I wrote in the question they are consider duplicate if ALL members are the same.

Comment: Then why should group 1 be in the answer, clearly one of the rows in that group is different?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT grpid
FROM TableWithGroups
GROUP BY grpid, userid, pct, hobby
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This uses the [GROUP BY and HAVING](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx/) clauses to respectively group up the values on the fields you specified to condense the duplicates into one row and filter where the count of rows condensed in each grouping was greater than 1 (in other words where there were duplicates).

Comment: this will only work for group of 1, and not even

Comment: @Nir I don't follow. It returns the results you said for your given example data when I run it.

Comment: @Nir - this is why you should provide your **own** DDL and your **own** DML as per my request comment under your question!

Comment: No it does not, your SQL return 2 which shouldn't. the fiddle is in the question.

Comment: @Nir Indeed it does return 2 (in addition to the results you're looking for) but your question doesn't explain why 2 wouldn't be returned even though it has a duplicate between rows 4 and 6. As far as your example shows, it is the same case as `grpid` 1 and 4. If you can clarify why `grpid` 2 is different and doesn't meet the criteria you specified then I can update my answer accordingly.